# Enabling button from another activity - Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity

I've created a login with SQLite on Eclipse, once the user enters their details it checks the database and returns true or false. If true is returned, I want the program to enable the 'My Account' button so that when the user exits the login form the My Account button is accessible.

The button is located in **activity_main.xml.**

The login works absolutely fine, it's just the button enabling.

The code below shows the error stated in the title. Do I need to use intents?

**Login.java**

```
if(success)
            {
                Log.d("login", "user logged");
                Button actBTN=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myaccountbtn);   
                session = true;
                actBTN.setEnabled(session);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("login", "user not logged");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have two activities: MainActivity and LoginActivity. The problems are that you are trying to access button in your MainActivity from LoginActivity. Android doesn't work this way - you have access only to your current view tree inflated from XML to particular activity. So I recommend to you take a look to [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/intents/result.html).You can handle your login flow inside LoginActivity, pass result back to MainActivity and then enable or disable button depending on login results.